# setTimeout помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript

Как это так получается, что после того, как `timerId` был присвоен метод с функцией, вызывающей модальное окно, в этой же функции снова вызывается функция `timerId`?

```js
let timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  alert('tick');
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: `timerId` это не функция, а `id` вашего `setTimeout`. А вообще это просто рекурсивный вызов, ничего необычного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, так это легче понять:

```js
function tick() {
  console.log('tick', timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}
let timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
```

Еще проще, так как `timerId` не используется:

```js
function tick() {
  console.log('tick');
  setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}
setTimeout(tick, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы не советовал использовать `setTimeOut()` в рекурсии, из-за риска переполнения стека вызовов.
В случаях, когда необходимо вызывать некоторую функцию интервально по времени в JS существует специальный метод `setInterval(handler, time)`.

Данный код можно переписать на:

```js
let timerId = setInterval(function() {
  alert('tick');
}, 2000);
```

При необходимости, можно остановить интервал:

```js
clearInterval(timerId);
```

Comment: здесь нет рекурсии, как следствие - нет риска переполнения стека. Как раз из-за `setTimeout`

Comment: Кроме того, есть разница при выполнении кода с `setInterval` и кода из вопроса